Probability of reaching a specific state exactly n times

Given states $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and probability matrix
$$P= \begin{bmatrix}
  0.2 & 0.8 &  0 & 0&0\\
  0 & 0.4 & 0.6&0&0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0.6&0.4&0 \\
  0.2&0&0&0.6&0.2 \\
  0&0&0&0&1
 \end{bmatrix}$$
if a Markov chain starts from state $1$, how do I calculate a probability of entering state $4$ exactly $4$ times?

I'm not sure how to start. What's bugging me the most is that it should be exactly 4 times. How to approach it?

You could try breaking down the problem into smaller parts. What is the probability of never getting to state 4?

I'm not sure. I tried changing state 4 to an absobing one and then calculate the probability of hitting state 5 before state 4, but I just get zeros. Idk what I'm doing wrong.

With probability $1$ a chain in state $1$ will eventually transition to state $2$, since state $1$ can only go to itself or state $2$. Similarly a chain in state $2$ ($3$) will go to state $3$ ($4$) with probability $1$.
A chain in state $4$ gets absorbed with probability $0.2$ (and never visits state $4$ again), but the other $0.8$ of the time it either stays in state $4$ (which counts as another visit) or transitions to state $1$ which with probability $1$ will lead back to state $4$. So if the chain is in state $4$ the probability is $0.8$ that there will be another visit to state $4$.
From the initial state, state $4$ is first reached with probability $1$, and then $4$ is visited exactly three more times with probability $0.8×0.8×0.8×0.2=0.1024$, which is the final answer.

Oh I see it now. This is a great explanation. Thank you!
